# Finding changes in a Git merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Using git bisect I found the culprit commit - it is a merge commit (I'm on the master branch)

I'm trying to isolate the buggy code but the merge included some commits from the merged branch and I don't know how can I view the full changes between the merge commit and the commit before it (the previous working commit in the master)

Is there a way to do so in GIT?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a git diff with the parents.

The first parent is given with SHA1^ and the second parent with SHA1^2 :

```
git diff mergeSHA1^ mergeSHA1
git diff mergeSHA1^2 mergeSHA1
```

You can see the docs of [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) for more details

Comment: You have the order of the arguments backwards, but your commands are basically correct.  Using the order `git diff mergeSHA1 mergeSHA1^` will show you a reverse of the changes from the merge commit and the first parent.  I think the original poster wants the unreversed changes, which you can get with `git diff mergeSHA1^ mergeSHA1`.

Answer (score 1):

[`git diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) displays differences between commits. The variation you want is probably this:

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
> ```
>
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

So for your case, use sha1 of the merge commit for the other, and sha1 of the commit that you want to compare it to as the other.

```
git diff <sha1 of the commit to compare to> <sha1 of merge commit>
```

You could also use `^` operator to compare to parents of the merge commit. `sha1^` would be the first parent and `sha1^2` would be the second, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7211140/1615903).

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, but you probably want to change the order of the arguments to `<sha1 of the commit to compare it to> <sha1 of merge commit>`, since the original order will show the changes in reverse.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian fixed, thanks. I never get it right on the first try :P