# GIT get the commit hash prior to a specific commit

Tags: git, shell, centos

git 1.7.1

`git show <hash>:<file>` gives me the file based on the commit hash provided

I am trying to figure out how to bet the file of the previous commit before the one who's hash I have.

I know I can always use the `log` to get all hashes and figure out the one i need but that's not a good solution in my case as I am trying to minimise the number of commands I need to do for performance issues.

Was wondering if there is a simple way.

Comment: Are you looking to go *backwards* through history, from commit to (one of its) parent(s), or *forwards*, from commit to (one of its) child(ren)?  The former is trivial (use the `^` or `~` notations), the latter is difficult (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git).

Comment: I am trying to go backwards.

Comment: `git show --format="%P" <SHA>` shows you all parents of a given `SHA`. Tested it on `git 1.8.5.2`. Took the answer from this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7211140/630866

Comment: Your title doesn't specify this is the commit has of a specific file. I need the general last commit and only the hash.

Comment: I don't follow. Can you please rephrase.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `git show HEAD^1`. You can replace `HEAD` with your commit-hash

### Edit to take multiple parents into account:

In case you want to see all the parents for a commit hash, you can use `git rev-list --parents -n 1 <commithash>` or use `git show` as @Bhaskar suggested in the comments to the question.

There are other ways as well as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059633/2279816).

Comment: If `HEAD` has more than one parent, this command will only show you the first one of them.

Comment: @Jubobs If HEAD has more than one parent, then what the OP is trying to do is inherently ambiguous, and there's probably not one good answer in that case. Using `git show <sha>^1:<file>` will show the file as it exists in the first parent, and will be what is wanted most of the time...

Comment: @twalberg True. My comment was only a remark, not a criticism.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on commit message:
`git log | grep -A <number_of_lines> <commit_hash> <number_of_lines>`