# Git checkout to a commit 2 commits before hash

Tags: git, hash, git-checkout

I have to revert a change made to a file, on many branches, on many repos. I know I can use git checkout hash filename and then push that change.

The problem is, I only know the has two commits before the actual commit I want to revert to.

How can I ask git what's the hash of two commits before this has and use it to properly revert?

Comment: If the revision history is A-B-C-D-E (with E being newest), and you want to revert to C, are you saying you know A, or you know E?

Comment: git commits know their parents, but since they can have any number of children (branches) a shortcut to "x commits ahead" would make no sense. So if you're looking for 2 commit back, the answer is `hash~2`, but if for 2 commits ahead then there is no easy way

Comment: So I know of a git hash some where that's either E or before E. It may or may not be the latest. So let's say I know E. I need to say git checkout to C.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664323/git-get-the-commit-hash-prior-to-a-specific-commit/48775239#48775239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you need to look *backward* or *forward* from some particular commit.

The key to all of this, though, is to recognize that Git doesn't care very much at all about branch *names*.  What Git cares about is the *commit graph*.  Any time you are dealing with this sort of issue, you should *draw the graph*.

Here are some sample graphs.  Round `o` nodes represent commits.  The `*` is the commit whose ID you have in your hands, and I gave "potentially interesting" commits one-letter names:

```
...--A--o--*--o--B--...--o   <-- branchname
     ^           ^
   2 before    2 after
```

This graph is pretty easy.  Commit `A` comes two before commit `*`, so if you have the hash of `*`—let's say it's `1234567`—you can write `1234567~2`.  The `~2` means "go back two first-parents" (see below).  Finding commit `B` is tougher (see below).

But we might have this mess:

```
                o--D--o   <-- branch1
               /
              /  E--o     <-- branch2
      A--o   /  /    \
          \ /  /      \
...--B--o--*--o--F-...-o   <-- branch3
            \         /
             o--C----o
```

Here, commits `A` and `B` are *both* two steps before `*`, while all of `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` are two steps *after*.

It is much easier, in Git, to find commits that are "before", because Git's internal arrows all point "backwards".  The branch names, which are all on the right and hence point to the *latest* commit on the branch—this is in fact how branches work in Git: the name points to the *tip* commit, and the tip commit points backwards (leftward in these graphs) to earlier commit(s)—simply get Git started in terms of finding commits.

Given a commit, Git follows the backwards arrow(s) to the parent(s) of that commit.  Here `*` is a merge commit, bringing the `A--o` and `B--o` lines together.

The order of the two parents of `*` is not something shown in the graph itself but let's say that the `A` line is actually found via the *second* parent.  Let's say that `*` is again `1234567`.  Then `1234567~2` is commit `B` (not `A`) because `~` follows only *first* parents.  To find `A`, you can write `1234567^2` (which names the upper `o` before `*`) and then add `^1` or `~1` to go back one more parent to `A`.

In other words, the two commits are now `1234567~2` and `1234567^2~1`.  (There are more ways to write this.)  But the easiest thing is to run `git log --graph --oneline 1234567` and observe the graph—Git will draw it vertically but you'll see two lines come out of `*`, which will let you find both `A` and `B`.

If there are more than two ways to get to more than two commits that are "two steps back", you'll see that in the graph, as we do for the many commits that are "two steps forward".  But ... to *find* the commits that are "two steps forward" is noticeably much harder.

Again, Git starts from the newest (rightmost in our drawings) *tip* commits and works backwards.  I drew three things that eventually merge into the tip of `branch3`,<sup>1</sup> but note that commit `D`—which is also two steps forward—can be found *only* by searching backwards from `branch1`.

#### There is no "search forward"

Git has no way to "search forward" or "step forward" from a commit.  All operations that move forward (there is one!) actually work by moving backwards.  Basically, we start from *all possible starting points*, i.e., *all* branch names / tips.<sup>2</sup>  Then we have Git list *everything* that goes back to the commit we want, printing those commit's hash IDs if and only if they are *descendants*<sup>3</sup> of the commit we're looking at.

The command that prints all these IDs is `git rev-list` (which is actually just `git log`,<sup>4</sup> told to only print the commits' hash IDs instead of logging the commits.)  The *flag* that says "give me descendants" is `--ancestry-path`, and it must be combined with several more pieces of information.  In particular, we must tell Git which commit is the "interesting" one, and we do that with the `^` prefix (not suffix this time):

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path ^1234567 --branches
```

The `^1234567` tells Git which commit stops the graph traversal *and* limits the set of printed revisions to those that are descendants of `1234567`.  The `--branches` tells Git, as usual, where to *start* the search: from all branch tips.  (We can also add `--tags`, or use `--all` to say *all references: all branches, all tags, the stash if there is one, and whatever else may exist.*  However, `--branches`, or `--branches --tags`, is probably what you want here.)

Now, the problem with `git rev-list` is that it just spills out all the revision IDs.  That includes not just commits `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`, but also all the "uninteresting" `o` commits that come after commit `*`.  There are numerous possible solutions to this, but perhaps the simplest is to go back to using `git log --graph --oneline`: that will, instead of printing just the (full) hash, print (abbreviated) hashes and commit messages, plus draw the graph.  Now you can eyeball the graph to find commits that are "two ahead".

(Of course, since `git log` and `git rev-list` are basically the same command, you can also run `git rev-list --graph`.  There is no need for `--oneline` since the output is one commit ID per line anyway.  But `git rev-list` is a *plumbing* command, meant for use in scripts, and is not very user-friendly, while `git log` is meant for interacting with users, and tries to be more immediately-useful.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This three-parent merge is a thing called an "octopus merge" and is uncommon in practice.  More typically you'd have two merges, one that brings `branch2` into `branch3`, and another—earlier or later—that brings the now-unnamed bottom-row line of commits into `branch3`.

<sup>2</sup>We might also want to start from tags.  For instance, consider this graph fragment:

```
...--o--*--o--o   <-- branch
         \
          o--o    <-- tag: v0.98alpha
```

Here, version 0.98alpha was deemed "bad", and the two commits reachable from the tag are no longer on *any* branch.  But if it turns out that one of those two commits has some precious data or code in it, you can still find it, by starting from the tag, and if needed, working backwards to the previous commit.  The commit two-steps-back here, marked `*`, is also on branch `branch`, so you would find that even without starting from tag `v0.98alpha`.

<sup>3</sup>In these directed graphs that Git uses, an *ancestor* is any commit you can reach by starting from some commit and working backwards: the commit itself, any of its parents, any of its parents' parents—any of its grandparents—and so on.  This is the same meaning as "ancestors" for yourself, except that in Git, you are considered your own ancestor.

Because Git's arrows point backwards, it's easy to find ancestors.

The term "descendants" works the same: you are your own descendant, but your children and grandchildren and great-grandchildren are also your descendants, just as you would expect.  Git can't actually *find* these grandchildren directly, but given a *pair* of commits, there is a very easy test for "is commit *Y* a descendant of commit *X*": we just reverse the test.  For *Y* to be a descendant of *X*, *X* must be an ancestor of *Y*.  Since Git *can* answer the "is ancestor" question, we reverse the test and get our answer.

<sup>4</sup>There are a few significant differences between `git log` and `git rev-list`, so they're not *quite* the same command.  But they are build from the same source code and *can* do exactly the same thing, depending on options.  They just set up different options by default: `log` prints human-readable things, uses a pager, uses color output, and so on; while `rev-list` prints machine-readable things and does not use a pager.  The flags needed to make one act like the other are not always obvious, either.

Comment: very detailed. thanks. I needed to get to commit A. ~2 worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git rev-list --parents -n 2 <commithash>` to get to the commit 2 before your hash.

Answer (score 3):

Use git log to see the modifications made to the file:

```
git log myfile
```

When you figured out the commit hash you want to revert to, use

```
git checkout thehash myfile
```