# Can git log show commits around a given commit-id like "-C x" for grep command?

Tags: git

Command like `grep -C 3 key file.txt`, can show 3 lines context around the matched line.
I'm wondering if git log can do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List commits between 2 commit hashes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git)

Comment: ... Though that will still require some machinations to find the commit IDs of the surrounding commits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664323/git-get-the-commit-hash-prior-to-a-specific-commit has some tips around that.

Comment: Straight `git log` can't, but `git grep` can. Consider using that on each "interesting" commit. Since commits are snapshots, you may find too many matches this way; combine `git log` and `git grep` to trim these down. (Note that `git rev-list` is the plumbing variant of `git log`, at least for most cases, so it's usually the step you want instead of `git log` here.)

Comment: hi @0stone0, thanks for the link, but it's not exactly what I dream. And thanks all the comments~